# Disable Docs menu entry in Storybook

Tags: storybook, nextjs-storybook

Prior to version 7, the "Docs" were available as a tab at the top *after* opening a story from sidebar like this:
[image]

However in version 7, "Docs" were removed from the tab and are now available from the sidebar menu, which clutters the menu space. How can I override and disable this per story or globally? Can I switch back to old way (Docs as a card)?

before / after
[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I also like it better the old way

Answer (score 1):

Check the main.js in .storybook. Add or update **autodocs** to **false**, it works for me

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  docs: {
    autodocs: false
  },
  ...
};
```